# Can you switch from Async PostBack to Full PostBack in an Update Panel?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, updatepanel

Is something like this possible?

```
Dim iCounter as Integer
Dim iQuantity as Integer = 10

Protected Sub btnFoo_Click Handles btnFoo Yadda

    For i as Integer = iCounter to iQuantity - 1
        //do something with AsyncPostBackTrigger until iCounter = iQuantity - 1
        //then trigger a full postback
    Next

End Sub
```

I am new to the concept and feel like there must be something really easy that I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going into why, what I eventually did was store the counter in a session variable and exited the sub from the for loop unless the counter was equal to the quantity.

Then everything past the end of the for loop that I needed updated (Labels, DropDownBoxes) I put in their own update panels with UpdateMode set to always.

To modify my pseudo code above:

```
Dim iCounter as Integer = Session("counter")
Dim iQuantity as Integer = 10

Protected Sub btnFoo_Click Handles btnFoo Yadda

    For i as Integer = iCounter to iQuantity - 1
        //do something with AsyncPostBackTrigger until iCounter = iQuantity - 1
        //then trigger a full postback

        If iCounter <> iQuantity Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Session("counter") = iCounter + 1
    Next

    //Everything else I needed to do with page controls wrapped 
    //in their own update panels

End Sub
```

Maybe not the 'best practice' but it worked for what I needed.